# How to find sharepoint path

Tags: 2010, 2013, path

I am new to SharePoint.  I have an Excel workbook that has a macro that opens a power point slide.  When the slide that it wants to open resides in a Windows directory (C:\ etc) everything works fine, I just specify the full path and file name.  I recently moved the power point slide to SharePoint and I can't for the life of me figure out how to find the path to the slide.

Full disclosure, this is the second time I have moved a power point slide to SharePoint for similar opening by an Excel macro.  Somehow I found the path the first time and the macro works fine, but I have no idea how I did it.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint files can be access via a web URL. So to find that URL you can open the browser, then type the SharePoint site url. Then choose the library/folder you uploaded the file.

Then you can right click the file and copy the URL. You can validate the URL by putting the URL in a new tab, which will open the file.

Another option is to open the library which has the file in Explorer (You can use Library tab from the ribbon and click on open in explorer button). Then copy the file path.

Comment: Thank You Amal.  That worked.  I was trying to copy he URL from the address bar (Like I do in windows).  For some reason that didnt work.  Oddly once your method worked I retried to copy it from the adress bar and that also worked.  Not sure what I was doing yesterday ...

Answer (score 0):

First find the path from the URL.  In Share Point it will be somehting like:
https://TLDomainName.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/DocumentLibrary/FolderName/

If you open with FILE Explorer, you should be able to get there if you have access...  however, SOMETIMES you may have to open the location with Internet Explorer in order to open with FILE EXPLORER.

Once you are there in FILE EXPLORER, click on the folder that you want to get the path to select it.

In the File Explorer top menu under FILE ribon, you  should see 'copy path" as a choice.  Click it and save to notepad to view it...

It will look something like:
"\TLDomainName.sharepoint.com@SSL\MainWWWRoot\sites\Sitename\DocumentLibrary/FolderName"

I hope this helps.